# Create one custom QML signal for several properties

Tags: qt, properties, signals, qml

I have an `Item` composed of several `properties`:

```
Item
{
    id: propertiesList
    property CustomLabel phone: { text: dataFromServer.phone }
    property CustomLabel age: { text: dataFromServer.age}
}
```

I'd like to trigger a signal when the `text` of one of the `properties` is changed:

```
onTextChanged
{
    doSomething(phone/age.text)
}
```

I could create one signal for each property but I don't find this very clean. Is there a way to create one signal for all `properties` that would handle the `text` variable ?

EDIT:

**CustomLabel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Label
{
    signal textChanged(string updatedText)

    font.pixelSize: 22
    font.italic: true
    color: "steelblue"
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What do you want to do?

Comment: The triggered signal would call a C++ method that would update the text of another QML Item. Explaining why I need to do this would greatly expand the scope of the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a signal that is triggered when the `text` in the `CustomLabel` is changed. Then you can connect the signals to a signal in your `Item`. Like this

```
Item
 {
     id: propertiesList
     signal textChanged(string updatedText)

     property CustomLabel phone: { text: dataFromServer.phone, onTextChanged: doSomething(updatedText) }
     property CustomLabel age: { text: dataFromServer.age, onTextChanged: doSomething(updatedText) }
 }
```

**-- UPDATE --**

Check [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#signal-handler-attributes). It says

> Property Change Signal Handlers
>
> Signal handlers for property change signal take the syntax form
>   *on<Property>Changed* where *<Property>* is the name of the property, with
>   the first letter capitalized. For example, although the TextInput type
>   documentation does not document a textChanged signal, this signal is
>   implicitly available through the fact that TextInput has a text
>   property and so it is possible to write an onTextChanged signal
>   handler to be called whenever this property changes:

So, as Label has also a text property, it has also the textChanged signal. I think that you have a conflict with the two signals (the original that Label has because the text property and the one you create in `CustomLabel`). Give another name to your `textChanged` signal in `CustomLabel` and it should work.

Comment: I submitted an edit for your answer. This does help me, however I am getting a `ReferenceError: text is not defined` when app is running. I supposed it's because the variables are not instantiated. How could I fix this without declaring my values as objects? (not sure if I'm clear, I want to keep them as `properties`)

Comment: Did you create the signal in the `CustomLabel` with a parameter called `updatedText`? Like this `signal textChanged(string updatedText)`

Comment: I did. I also tried to put it in the Item instead. Same error.

Comment: Can you share the `CustomLabel` implementation?

Comment: See first post. Could it be because my `property` is not yet instantiated? It seems like the signal doesn't exist yet.